# allocate a std::initializer_list with given size

Tags: c++, list

I want to allocate a `std::initializer_list` and later add elements to
it in a loop.

```
std::size_t size; 
std::initializer_list<float> tmp; //<- allocate size_t float elements
```

I looked at examples but found nothing regarding this type.

Comment: Can I suggest you to use std::array or std::vector? default_initializer_list is not supposed to be used as this, just as a way to provide literal initialization values.

Comment: What is a default_initializer_list? I can't find any trace of it.

Comment: @MatthieuH sorry, I made an edit

Comment: Use an `std::vector` (or `std::array` if you know the size at compile-time). Initializer lists should not be constructed directly and are used to make initialization of certain classes easier on the caller's side.

Comment: Your `create()` function returns a dangling reference. Returning a reference to a local variable is bad because it will be destroyed at the function exit. Moreover, you can't dereference what's not a pointer so your preceding `*` should be removed as well.

Comment: The `create` function is bugged even if you could get it to compile. You cannot sensibly return a reference to a newly created object. Change the function return type to `Vector`.

Comment: please don't completely change your question, especially after someone has posted an answer, if you have a new question, post a new question

Answer (score 4):

`std::initializer_list` is a proxy object which underlying type is `const T[N]` (where `N` and `T` are deduced from input arguments), so no, you cannot really change anything in this object after initialisation.

Comment: Even more important, it doesn't actually hold the values, it's more like a view.

Comment: I made an edit to my question - I wanted to be too general. I want to use std::initializer_list as an argument in my constructor to initialize a vector.

Comment: @awwd in this case you may provide another constructor, that takes more flexible type of argument. Be advised, however, that despite this question falls into XY category, [it's not embraced to change questions to the extent that it invalidates existing answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302443/is-it-acceptable-to-drastically-change-a-question-after-youve-got-an-answer-st)